# Putting current location into maps application

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

I am trying to add a way of viewing my current location to my application and can't figure out how to do it without getting errors. I currently have the two incorrectly stored in separate activities (Markers locations in one activity and my location in other activity) and can't seem to combine them. 
Sorry about the poor attempt at describing my problem, hopefully this code will help more.

```
MainActivity    

package com.kieranmaps.v2maps;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.kieranmaps.v2maps.R;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.naming.Md5FileNameGenerator;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.memory.impl.FIFOLimitedMemoryCache;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.QueueProcessingType;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.SimpleImageLoadingListener;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private final LatLng OREILLYS = new LatLng(53.348347, -6.254119);
    private final LatLng LAGOONA = new LatLng(53.349810, -6.243160);
    private final LatLng COPPERS = new LatLng (53.335356, -6.263481);
    private final LatLng WRIGHTS = new LatLng (53.445491, -6.223857);
    private final LatLng ACADEMY = new LatLng (53.348045,-6.26198);
    private final LatLng DICEYS = new LatLng (53.347250, -6.254198);
    private final LatLng PYGMALION = new LatLng (53.342183,-6.262358);
    private final LatLng FIBBERS = new LatLng (53.352799,-6.260412);
//  private final LatLng TEST = new LatLng (5352799,-6.260412);


    private Marker marker;
    private Hashtable<String, String> markers;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        initImageLoader();
        markers = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher)      //  Display Stub Image
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_launcher)   //  If Empty image found
            .cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc().bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();

        if ( googleMap != null ) {

            googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());

            final Marker oreillys = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(OREILLYS)
                        .title("O Reillys"));
            markers.put(oreillys.getId(), "http://img.india-forums.com/images/100x100/37525-a-still-image-of-akshay-kumar.jpg");

            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(OREILLYS, 15));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

            final Marker coppers = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(COPPERS)
                    .title("Coppers"));
            markers.put(coppers.getId(), "http://f3.thejournal.ie/media/2011/11/coppers1-390x285.png");

            final Marker wrights = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(WRIGHTS)
                    .title("The Wright Venue"));
            markers.put(wrights.getId(), "http://www.turbosound.com/public/images/news_img_thumbs/Wright_Venue_Dancefloor-thumb.jpg");

            final Marker lagoona = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LAGOONA)
                    .title("The Lagoona"));
            markers.put(lagoona.getId(), "http://www.turbosound.com/public/images/news_img_thumbs/Wright_Venue_Dancefloor-thumb.jpg");

            final Marker academy = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ACADEMY)
                    .title("The Academy"));
            markers.put(academy.getId(), "http://www.turbosound.com/public/images/news_img_thumbs/Wright_Venue_Dancefloor-thumb.jpg");

            final Marker pygmalion = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(PYGMALION)
                    .title("The Pygmalion"));
            markers.put(pygmalion.getId(), "http://www.turbosound.com/public/images/news_img_thumbs/Wright_Venue_Dancefloor-thumb.jpg");

            final Marker fibbers = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(FIBBERS)
                    .title("Fibbers"));
            markers.put(fibbers.getId(), "http://www.turbosound.com/public/images/news_img_thumbs/Wright_Venue_Dancefloor-thumb.jpg");

            final Marker diceys = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(DICEYS)
                    .title("Dicey's"));
            markers.put(diceys.getId(), "https://dublinnow.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/diceys.jpg");

     /*     final Marker diceys = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(DICEYS)
            .title("Diceys")
            .snippet("Drink Deal: 3.50. Adm: 5, Performance: Gen"));

            Marker marker = GoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("Title")
            .snippet("Snippet")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.marker))); */

//marker.showInfoWindow();
        }

    }

    private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

        private View view;

        public CustomInfoWindowAdapter() {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window,
                    null);
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            if (MainActivity.this.marker != null
                    && MainActivity.this.marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                MainActivity.this.marker.hideInfoWindow();
                MainActivity.this.marker.showInfoWindow();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {
            MainActivity.this.marker = marker;

            String url = null;

            if (marker.getId() != null && markers != null && markers.size() > 0) {
                if ( markers.get(marker.getId()) != null &&
                        markers.get(marker.getId()) != null) {
                    url = markers.get(marker.getId());
                }
            }
            final ImageView image = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge));

            if (url != null && !url.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                    && !url.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                imageLoader.displayImage(url, image, options,
                        new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                                    View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                                super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view,
                                        loadedImage);
                                getInfoContents(marker);
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }
//
            final String title = marker.getTitle();
            final TextView titleUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
            if (title != null) {
                titleUi.setText(title);
            } else {
                titleUi.setText("");
            }

            final String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
            final TextView snippetUi = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.snippet));
            if (snippet != null) {
                snippetUi.setText(snippet);
            } else {
                snippetUi.setText("");
            }

            return view;
        }
    }

    private void initImageLoader() {
        int memoryCacheSize;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
            int memClass = ((ActivityManager) 
                    getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
                    .getMemoryClass();
            memoryCacheSize = (memClass / 8) * 1024 * 1024;
        } else {
            memoryCacheSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
        }

        final ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                this).threadPoolSize(5)
                .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
                .memoryCacheSize(memoryCacheSize)
                .memoryCache(new FIFOLimitedMemoryCache(memoryCacheSize-1000000))
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO).enableLogging() 
                .build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    }
}
```

NewActivity:

```
package com.kieranmaps.v2maps;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

public class NewActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap map;
    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;

    private double sourceLatitude, sourceLongitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initializing 
        markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
        map = fm.getMap();

        // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);     

        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 0,
                mlocListener);
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                10, 0, mlocListener);

//      // Setting onclick event listener for the map
//      map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {
//          
//          @Override
//          public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
//              
//              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//              
//              // Already two locations                
//              if(markerPoints.size()>1){
//                  markerPoints.clear();
//                  map.clear();                    
//              }
//              
//              // Adding new item to the ArrayList
//              markerPoints.add(point);                
//              
//              // Creating MarkerOptions
//              MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
//              
//              // Setting the position of the marker
//              options.position(point);
//              
//              /** 
//               * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
//               * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
//               */
//              if(markerPoints.size()==1){
//                  options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
//              }else if(markerPoints.size()==2){
//                  options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
//              }
//                          
//              
//              // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
//              map.addMarker(options);
//              
//              // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
//              if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){                   
//                  LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
//                  LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);
//                  
//                  // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
//                  String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);                
//                  
//                  DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
//                  
//                  // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
//                  downloadTask.execute(url);
//              }
//              
//          }
//      });

    }

    private void sourceTodestination() {        
        // Source
        LatLng point = new LatLng(sourceLatitude, sourceLongitude);

        // Destination
        double destLatitude = 23.7383;
        double destLongitude = 90.3958;
        LatLng point1 = new LatLng(destLatitude, destLongitude);

        CameraUpdate center=
                CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng((sourceLatitude + destLatitude)/2, (sourceLongitude + destLongitude)/2));
            CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13);

            map.moveCamera(center);
            map.animateCamera(zoom);

        // Adding new item to the ArrayList
        markerPoints.add(point);    

        markerPoints.add(point1);   

        // Creating MarkerOptions
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

        // Setting the position of the marker
        options.position(point);

        /** 
         * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
         * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
         */
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));

        MarkerOptions options1 = new MarkerOptions();
        options1.position(point1);
        options1.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));

        // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
        map.addMarker(options);
        map.addMarker(options1);

        // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
        if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){                   
            LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
            LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

            // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
            String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);                

            DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

            // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
            downloadTask.execute(url);
        }
    }

    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;      


        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";         

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;


        return url;
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                        sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
     }



    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{         

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;        
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
            super.onPostExecute(result);            

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);

        }       
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread        
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject; 
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;                     

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);    
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);                 

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng); 

                    points.add(position);                       
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(2);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);   

            }

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            map.addPolyline(lineOptions);                           
        }           
    }   

    /* Class My Location Listener */
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

            sourceLatitude = loc.getLatitude();
            sourceLongitude = loc.getLongitude();

            sourceTodestination();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sourceLatitude + " - " + sourceLongitude,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            android.util.Log.v("", "Latitud = ");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            android.util.Log.v("", "status = ");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }   
}
```

JSON Parser

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class DirectionsJSONParser {

    /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
    public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;    

        try {           

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){            
                jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                    jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                            path.add(hm);                       
                        }                               
                    }
                    routes.add(path);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){           
        }


        return routes;
    }   


    /**
     * Method to decode polyline points 
     * Courtesy : http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java 
     * */
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
}
```

Forgive me for my ignorance but I can't figure out how to get it working with both of these. Any tips appreciated! thanks
edit: More details, I can only get this working showing the locations but I can't get it to show my current location and route to those destinations

Answer (score 0):

Your current location is the loc from this method

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
```

apply accuracy to your loc location to get a accurate location.  accuracy threshold is up to you.  less than 30m is fine.